# Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to type address

Tags: solidity

I don't know why I'm getting these compilation errors. The implicit conversion error is for lines 19-21, 27-30, and 34-35. The invalid type error is for line 36. Thanks for your help!

[image: source code]

[image: error messages]

Comment: Please include the code as text to make it easier to test and suggest changes. The error means you are trying to use two incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

because `items` is a `mapping` type that maps an `address` to an struct of type `S_Item`. the `itemIndex` variable is of type `uint` and is not of type `address` which you passed to `items[itemIndex]`

Comment: Could you suggest a solution? I'm new to Solidity I appreciate your help!! Thanks!!

Comment: you sent the image of your code please send the code then I can fix it for you